# Is it possible to modify the ASP.NET bundler to include a version number with the bundled files?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

I have started working recently with the new .net feature of bundling and minification as outlined by scott gu - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx in mvc4 application.

I have some questions though, or problems that I am not sure how to resolve.

Firstly my application is installed on a web farm with multiple we servers. Does the bundling library create a file on disk and if so how would this work in a scenario that a page is requested from server 1 but the request for the bundled javascript file is on web 2?

Is it possible to modify the bundler to include a version number with the bundled files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not create a file.  But it does add the bundle to the output cache, so a new bundle does not have to be created with each request.

Regarding a web farm, it doesn't matter.  Each server will generate it's own bundle and store it in its own cache.

Bundling and Minification includes a version number already, so that when the bundle changes it will break through the cache.  This version number is actually a computed hash of the minified bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can add an incremental version number, but this will produce a URL with a hash of the bundled files in the query string:

```
System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/styles/site")
```